# Process start time and running time do not match

Tags: linux, centos, time, ps

We have a situation where times present by **START TIME** and **TIME** presented by "ps" are not matching. When I say matching I mean - **TIME** shows that a service is running longer than it actually is.

Example:

```
someuser    29953  7.9 30.2 4928524 1171844 ?     Sl   15:47   2:10 /some/process

# date
Thu Mar 22 16:15:28 UTC 2018

# stat /proc/29953
  File: ‘/proc/29953’
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 1024   directory
Device: 3h/3d   Inode: 134924297   Links: 9
Access: (0555/dr-xr-xr-x)  Uid: (6198888/   someuser)   Gid: (6198882/somegroup)
Context: system_u:system_r:unconfined_service_t:s0
Access: 2018-03-22 15:47:41.571718526 +0000
Modify: 2018-03-22 15:47:41.571718526 +0000
Change: 2018-03-22 15:47:41.571718526 +0000
 Birth: -
```

Running time appears to be 2 hours and 10 minutes, while the service was started only 30 minutes ago.
How is this possible?  Why is "TIME" being show incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

2:10 running time means 2 minutes 10 seconds.

Comment: And is time the process was using CPU time. If the process stays there doing nothing, the counter is not incremented.